# Flex newbie on using HGroup and VGroup to control layout

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to learn Flex layout using VGroup and HGroup. As a simple exercise, I want to control the pixel-placement of button pairs. The code below attempts to place 3 pairs of buttons each in two rows. For example, the first row has a button pair 20 pixels from the top and left; another button pair 20 pixels from the top and centered; and another button pair 20 pixels from the top and right. The 2nd row has just all the buttons aligned 20 pixels to left.

It should look something like:

```
button button                     button button                   button button
button button button button button button
```

But the code produces no difference between the two rows. Can anyone help me understand how to control the layout like I'm intending?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" 
           minHeight="600">

<s:VGroup top="20" left="20" right="20">

    <s:HGroup top="20" left="20" right="20">

        <s:Button label="row1 left1"/>
        <s:Button label="row1 left2"/>

        <s:HGroup  horizontalAlign="center">
            <s:Button label="row1 middle1"/>
            <s:Button label="row1 middle2"/>
        </s:HGroup>

        <s:HGroup right="20">
            <s:Button label="row1 right1"/>
            <s:Button label="row1 right2"/>
        </s:HGroup>

    </s:HGroup>

    <s:HGroup top="50" left="20">
        <s:Button label="row2 left1"/>
        <s:Button label="row2 left2"/>
        <s:Button label="row2 middle1"/>
        <s:Button label="row2 middle2"/>
        <s:Button label="row2 right1"/>
        <s:Button label="row2 right2"/>
    </s:HGroup>

</s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

UPDATE: Based on Dom's answer below, here's the correct code for what I was intending:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" 
           minHeight="600">

<s:HGroup left="20" right="20" top="20">
    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Button click=""/>
        <s:Button click=""/>
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:Spacer width="100%"/>
    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Button click=""/>
        <s:Button click=""/>
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:Spacer width="100%"/>
    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Button click=""/>
        <s:Button click=""/>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:HGroup>
<s:VGroup left="20" right="20" top="50">
    <s:HGroup width="100%">
        <s:Button click=""/>
        <s:Button click=""/>
        <s:Button click=""/>
        <s:Button click=""/>
        <s:Button click=""/>
        <s:Button click=""/>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options:

1: dont use HGroup's

2: use HGroup's and space the items with

```
<s:Spacer width="x"/>
```

where x can be a % or exact pixels.

edit: properly formatted my answer so that s:spacer showed

edit 2: added code below:

```
<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:HGroup width="100%">
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:Button click=""/>
            <s:Button click=""/>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:Spacer width="100%"/>
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:Button click=""/>
            <s:Button click=""/>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:Spacer width="100%"/>
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:Button click=""/>
            <s:Button click=""/>
        </s:HGroup>
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:HGroup width="100%">
        <s:Button click=""/>
        <s:Button click=""/>
        <s:Button click=""/>
        <s:Button click=""/>
        <s:Button click=""/>
        <s:Button click=""/>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:VGroup>
```

That will look exactly like your example above.

Comment: Thanks Dom, For 1, do I just replace HGroup with Group? Or something else? For 2, if specify exact pixels, isn't that doing as above (e.g. `right="20"`, etc., or is there some other attribute you're intending to set pixels with?

Comment: 1: yes a Group would work just fine.  2: <s:Spacer width='x'/> is what you need

Comment: 1: If I set to Group for the first row all the buttons overlap. There must be some implied knowledge I'm missing. 2: Using Spacer won't work because the objects I'll be using (rather than the buttons here) will change dimensions in the application and I'll always need the right-most object (e.g. button here) to be aligned 20 pixels from right edge.

Comment: Sumpelest option, though it will take some trial and error to master is using hgroups and vgroups

Comment: Stand by. On iPad out smoking. I wii write something for you in a min

Comment: Thanks so much Dom, I was struggling for 1/2 a day on this. Your answer is excellent. I updated my posting above with a minor change for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

I really try to avoid spacers.  I think I've used one *once* to hack something into place... but it felt dirty.

The first row shouldn't be an `HGroup`, but a `Group` comprised of three `HGroup`s.  Like this, but without any spacers:

```
<s:VGroup top="20" left="20" right="20">

    <s:Group width="100%">

        <s:HGroup left="0">
            <s:Button label="row1 left1"/>
            <s:Button label="row1 left2"/>
        </s:HGroup>

        <s:HGroup horizontalCenter="0">
            <s:Button label="row1 middle1"/>
            <s:Button label="row1 middle2"/>
        </s:HGroup>

        <s:HGroup right="0">
            <s:Button label="row1 right1"/>
            <s:Button label="row1 right2"/>
        </s:HGroup>

    </s:Group>

    <s:HGroup top="50" left="20">
        <s:Button label="row2 left1"/>
        <s:Button label="row2 left2"/>
        <s:Button label="row2 middle1"/>
        <s:Button label="row2 middle2"/>
        <s:Button label="row2 right1"/>
        <s:Button label="row2 right2"/>
    </s:HGroup>

</s:VGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, your code places the middle buttons in the center of the container rather than equally spaced between the buttons on the left and right sides. This could be an advantage in my application. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Using spacers is a bit like playing a game on easy mode. It doesnt feel as good as doing it the normal way but you are guaranteed success quickly and easily. IMHO anyways.

Comment: I like that analogy... except that using spacers often has unintended side effects, like not properly centering things... and (not in your case) failing to adapt to size changes.  They are the 1px transparent gif of Flex :)

Comment: Brian, in avoiding the use of spacers, how would your code change if we wanted to keep an equal amount of space to the left and right of the middle pair of buttons in the first row? For example, imagine we have only 1 button on the right-side in the first row (instead of two), and we wanted the first row's middle pair of buttons NOT to be centered in the container, but centered between the left- and right-button groups in the first row (with equal space between each).